# cell info when the cell is clicked

Tags: c#, excel, events, excel-2007

Is it possible to show the cell info when any cell on a worksheet is clicked?
For example, if cell A1 is clicked it will show A1, and so on...
If yes, can you show example?

I need this because I have a c# program which should know which cell was clicked.

Comment: what do you mean by that? Excel already does that. I mean - it shows A1 when you are on A1.

Comment: hi, i am using c# code, in which i need to know which cell was clicked...

Comment: I'll delete my answer, since I don't have the C# knowledge to help you out, though I think it'll still be tied into a Worksheet Event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `WorksheetSelectionChange` event, there is sample code on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.selectionchange.aspx

```
private void WorksheetSelectionChange()
{
this.SelectionChange += 
    new Excel.DocEvents_SelectionChangeEventHandler(
    Worksheet1_SelectionChange);
}

void Worksheet1_SelectionChange(Excel.Range Target)
{
this.Application.StatusBar = this.Name + ":" +
    Target.get_Address(missing, missing,
    Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, missing, missing);
}
```